# Why do we need System class to call out.println() method?

Tags: java

When we want to print line in console we write System.out.println(data), what will be difference if we use PrintStream object out and use out.println(data).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we need System class to call out.println() method?

We don't.  It is just a convenient way to get hold of the `PrintStream` object for writing to standard output.

> ... what will be difference if we use PrintStream object out and use out.println(data).

It depends on how you obtained the `PrintStream` object.

- If you originally got the `PrintStream` object from `System.out` or `System.err`, then there is no difference; e.g. the following have the same effect:

  ```
  public void sayHello(PrintStream ps) {
      ps.println("hello");
  }
  sayHello(System.out);
  System.out.println("hello");
  ```
- If you created the PrintStream on a stream that opened yourself, the behaviour will be analogous, but the output will (most likely) go to a different place; e.g.

  ```
  sayHello(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("foo.txt"));
  ```

  will write "hello" to the named file.

There is nothing special about `System.in/out/err`.  They are just `public static final` variables that are initialized to specific stream objects when the JVM starts.  (OK, there is something slightly unusual about them ... but it doesn't manifest here.)

Answer (score 4):

`System.out` is a static reference to the `PrintStream` "out". So there is no difference.

```
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.println("Badgers");
```

Comment: `import static java.lang.System.out;` works just as well as aliasing and doesn't have to be done per method.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no difference. From [ProgrammerInterview.com](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/how-system-out-println-works/):

> Inside the `System` class is the declaration of `out` that looks like: `public static final PrintStream out`, and inside the `Printstream` class is a declaration of `println()` that has a method signature that looks like: `public void println()`.

`PrintStream` is a class which streams the data to the standard output. An association was made by adding the object which is `static` and `final` **out** in the `System` class. So we as programmers can use it as System the class name `(System.out)` out is static object of `PrintStream` class and `println( )` is a method in `PrintStream` class which are overloaded methods. So we directly write `System.out.println(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is a static `PrintStream` object which is bound to a special file of the System: the standard output. You can assign the reference of it to any other `PrintStream` variable.

Answer (score 0):

None, but `out` is commonly used as a variable in a program so it might be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

`println()` is a method in `PrintStream` class. out is the object of `PrintStream` class which is defined as static constant in `System` class with the address of console.

So, in whatever way we invoke that method it will be same.

But if you dont want to use `System` class, you need to create the `PrintStream` object by giving the standard output address.

Answer (score 0):

The words `System.out.println` have been used so much in the past that every casual reader of Java code knows what they mean. Everyone writes it this way, and people got accustomed to it.

The code would probably be harder to read if you first assigned `System.out` to a local variable. This is because in every line you would have to ask yourself: “Well, something gets printed, but *where*?”. The idiom `System.out.println` on the other hand answers that question. It clearly sticks out from the code as something being output (even if it is just for debugging purposes).

So yes, you *can* use a shortcut for `System.out.println`, but in most cases you shouldn't.